# How to make the Canvas cover other Canvas below?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have two overlapping canvases. I drew a line in the bottom canvas, and used `fillRect()` to draw in the top canvas, but the rectangle looks transparent even though I set opacity=1. What can I do to make the rectangle cover the lines completely?

Here's my code:

```js
var line_canvas = document.getElementById("line_canvas");
var test_canvas = document.getElementById("test_canvas");

var line_drawmap = line_canvas.getContext("2d");
var test_drawmap = test_canvas.getContext("2d");

line_drawmap.strokeStyle = "#000";
line_drawmap.beginPath();
line_drawmap.moveTo(100, 0);
line_drawmap.lineTo(100, 400);
line_drawmap.stroke();
line_drawmap.beginPath();
line_drawmap.moveTo(250, 0);
line_drawmap.lineTo(250, 400);
line_drawmap.stroke();

test_drawmap.globalAlpha = 1;
test_drawmap.fillStyle = "rgba(100,30,100,1)";
test_drawmap.fillRect(50, 50, 260, 160);
test_drawmap.font = "30px Microsoft YaHei";
test_drawmap.textAlign = "center"
test_drawmap.fillStyle = "#00FFFF";
test_drawmap.fillText("test", 240, 130);
test_drawmap.stroke();
```

```css
#background {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

#test {
  position:relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#line_canvas{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#test_canvas{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background">
  <div id="test">
    <canvas id="test_canvas" width="350" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">err</canvas>
    <canvas id="line_canvas" width="350" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">err</canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! This is my first question, I don't know the rules of good questioning, I'm sorry. I've added example code

Comment: Thanks. Does adding `z-index: 1;` to the test canvas CSS fix the problem in a way you expect? This just moves the canvas layer closer to the top.